# add extra values from other variable in php

Tags: php

I have two valriables in

```
$a="1:2:3";
$b="1:3:4:5";
```

Is there any simple method to add 4 and 5 in variable $a. Means i want the value of variable to be

```
$a="1:2:3:4:5"
```

Comment: concate them if you have static values.

Comment: if you used something that makes sense like an aarray instead of  a string then yes

Comment: its a dynamic value or static?

Comment: Yas i can concatenate them but it is dynamic and how i will find extra values of $b

Comment: no i cant use array here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one line solution:

```
$result = implode(':', array_unique(array_merge(explode(':', $a), explode(':', $b))));
```

An even shorter one would be:

```
$result = implode(':', array_unique(array_merge(explode(':', "$a:$b"))));
```

Comment: Nice and simple! Just been trying to figuring out this myself and forgot about array_unique()

Comment: great. I want like this

Comment: I've added even a little bit shorter solution.

Comment: Yes, the short answer is `$added = (strlen($result) - strlen($a))/2;`.

Longer answer (maybe a clearer approach) would be to modify the code: `$result = implode(':', $arrRes = array_unique(array_merge($arrA = explode(':', $a), explode(':', $b))));` and then it would be `$added = count($arrRes) - count($arrA);`.

Comment: BTW if this answers your question, please mark it as "answered" so that the community knows that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a2 = explode(":" , $a);
$b2 = explode(":" , $b);

foreach($b2 as $val)
{
    if(in_array($val , $a2))
        //do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$a="1:2:3";
$b="1:3:4:5";

$a = explode(':', $a);
$b = explode(':', $b);

$c = array_unique(array_merge($a,$b));

$a = implode(':', $c);

echo $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that $a is ordered, so you can apply sort to the new array

```
$sort = SORT_NUMERIC;
$a = implode(':',array_uniqe(array_merge(explode(':',$a),explode(':',$b)),$sort));
```

See [array_unique](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to other possible sorts.